# CSS3 inline layout is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with css3 inline layout, Please see this website footer  social icons are not coming inline
http://www.seoindiarank.com/

Please help me, Need help indeed!

[image]

Comment: Please remode <br> tag in your footer...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just remobe `<br>` tag from code; and give some padding for better look

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of `<br />` tags there. They are meant to be generating **new lines**. Please remove all the `<br />` tags from the footer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Godbless you dear :-)

Comment: Thank you guys! God bless you guys!

Comment: @ajaydeb You there? Are you even listening?